# Jquery-ui automplete suggestions menu width exceeding input box on smaller viewport

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery-ui's `autocomplete` with custom `bootstrap` styling.

For all viewports the size of menu panel would be exact same as input box size but if the string in menu is bigger then it just overflows the size of input box.

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I've tried adding width attributes to my css but it doesnt seem to work.

Demo: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohit1337/qegp9mp4/1/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add open callback function like this, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qegp9mp4/2/)

```
$("#coupon").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: coupons,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#label").val(ui.item.coupon);
        return false;
    },
    open: function() {
        $("ul.ui-menu").width( $(this).innerWidth() );
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
       $("#label").val(ui.item.coupon);
        return false;
    },
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
         return $("<li>")
             .append(item.label+ '<br><small class="form-text text-muted">' + item.desc+ '</small>')
             .appendTo(ul);
     };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the `min-height`or `min-height` css property to textbox or message box.